# Writing to a table after transformation (bonobo-sqlalchemy)

Tags: bonobo-etl

I'm trying to read a table, modify a column and write to another table. I followed the available documentation and ran following code. It doesn't give any errors, but the task doesn't get performed either.

I tried removing the transformation step and then information gets written.

```
import sqlalchemy
import bonobo
import bonobo_sqlalchemy


def get_services():
    return {
        'sql_alchemy.engine': sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/postgres')
    }

def transform(*row):
    new_row = row[0]+1, row[1]
    yield new_row


def get_graph(**options):
    graph = bonobo.Graph()
    graph.add_chain(bonobo_sqlalchemy.Select('SELECT * FROM users', engine='sql_alchemy.engine')
                    ,
                    transform,
                    bonobo_sqlalchemy.InsertOrUpdate(table_name='table_1', engine='sql_alchemy.engine'),
                    )
    return graph

# The __main__ block actually execute the graph.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = bonobo.get_argument_parser()
    with bonobo.parse_args(parser) as options:
        bonobo.run(get_graph(**options), services=get_services(**options))
```

Output:
 - Select in=1 out=6 [done]
 - format_for_db in=6 out=6 [done]
 - InsertOrUpdate in=6 out=6 [done]

Comment: There is a bug in `transform()`: you should `yield new_row`

Comment: @DanielReis Thanks. It has been corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

It works when a Dictionary is yielded as follows,

`yield  {"id": row[0], "text": row[1], "count":row[2]}`

with `bonobo.UnpackItems(0)` node in the chain after the transformation.